# Get next record from SQLite database when button is clicked

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have read notes about this but none seems to work for me. I have an SQLite database and with Netbeans as my IDE, I have a jframe that displays data records in a jtable, with records displayed in ascending order. Clicking on a record displays them in jtextfields.

I want to move to next record in database in ascending order when I click on a button, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
try{
    String sql ="select * from Employees order by Name ASC";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){

                int i = rs.getInt("ID");
                String idi= Integer.toString(i);
                id.setText(idi);
                String a = rs.getString("Name");
                name.setText(a);
                String b = rs.getString("Contact");
                contact.setText(b);
                String c = rs.getString("Email");
                email.setText(c);
                String d = rs.getString("Residence");
                residence.setText(d);
                String e = rs.getString("Job_Type");
                comboJob.setSelectedItem(e);

  }
        else {
             rs.previous();
             }

    }
    catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to store the values from database in an array and then iterate over it with your (prev,next) button like

```
i=0;
while(rs.next()) {
          dataset["ID"][i]=Integer.toString(rs.getInt("ID"));
          dataset["Name"][i]=rs.getString("EName");
   i++
          }
```

to display information you can use dataset array like

```
id.setText(dataset["ID"][i]);
name.setText(dataset["EName"][i]);
```

not checked syntax but the logic is correct.